# numeric only filter still allows entering of non-number characters

Tags: android, jquery

I have this code to filter a form field on a mobile device so that only numeric phone numbers are allowed:

```
$( document ).on( "keypress", ".numeric_only", function(e) {
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
             return false;
  }
});
```

The problem is, even with this it still allows people to enter characters like `-` or `.` especially on Android ..even if I allow only the numerical `tel` keyboard.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Comment: Did you try `e.preventDefault()` instead of return false?